# java.lang.NullPointerException error while running test ng case

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to run this code with TestNG but all it gives me is java.lang.NullPointerException error. Firefox does get opened but after that error comes up. What's going wrong. Please help!
Also is it mandatory to run testNG with XML.

```
 public class GuestCheckout 
  {

        public WebDriver driver ;
        public String baseURL = "http://www.google.com";

    @BeforeTest
    public void setBaseURL(){
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get(baseURL);
    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void EmailPasswordEntry() {
        // Entering Email and Password values

        driver.findElement(By.id("loginRegister")).click();
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("head_username"));
        email.clear();
        email.sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");

        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("head_password"));
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys("123456");

        driver.findElement(By.name("loginsubmit")).click();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    void AssertionVerification() {
        // Verifying "My Account" text after login
        String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='loginHeader']/descendant::a[text()='My Account']")).getText();
        Assert.assertTrue(bodyText.contains("My Accountii"), "Not matched");
    }   
  }



Error:
--------

    FAILED: EmailPasswordEntry
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at package_1.GuestCheckout.EmailPasswordEntry(GuestCheckout.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
        at `enter code here`org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

 and same for the second Test method
```

Comment: Please paste detailed error log.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have instantiated WebDriver in local way and trying use that as a global instance so you are getting Null Pointer Exception. Do this in this way:

```
public WebDriver driver ;
    public String baseURL = "http://www.ggolge.com";

@BeforeTest
public void setBaseURL(){
driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // Now this is a global instance for this class
driver.get(baseURL);
}

@Test(priority = 0)
public void EmailPasswordEntry() {
    // Entering Email and Password values

    driver.findElement(By.id("loginRegister")).click();
    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("head_username"));
    email.clear();
    email.sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");

    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("head_password"));
    password.clear();
    password.sendKeys("123456");

    driver.findElement(By.name("loginsubmit")).click();
}

@Test(priority = 1)
void AssertionVerification() {
    // Verifying "My Account" text after login
    String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='loginHeader']/descendant::a[text()='My Account']")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue(bodyText.contains("My Accountii"), "Not matched");
}
```

No it is not mandatory to run using TestNg xml, if you are using some intelligent IDE like Eclipse then you can run your tests without xml.

XMLs are beneficial when you have multiple classes to run all together as a suite.

Comment: Thanks alot Priyanshu..that worked! As i am new to test Ng can you pls advice from where can I get start learning

Answer (score 0):

since using webdriver... try using public static

> `public static webdriver driver`

in each class files